# "Press ENTER or type command to continue" in vim when enabling neocomplete plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neocomplcache

As soon as I enable neocomplete in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1
```

I keep getting

> NORMAL › +1 ~2 -281  ›  1:.vimrc
>   1:.vimrc
>   1:.vimrc
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

Message every time I open a file. How can I get rid of that "Press Enter" message after enabling neocomplete?

Comment: Did you try neocomplete's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing this setting with the previous fuzzy search program called neocomplcache. Try this setting if you are using neocomplete and **not** neocomplcance:

```
let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
```

Regards